# Google API V3 - Which one to use?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have few questions about the google map v3 which I am planning to use it my intranet website. Before that

1)

I tried sample application by using the below URLs.Both working fine.

Which one is best ? seems both belongs to V3 ? Can i use it for free ?

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

2)

Am planning to use this v3 URL to locate my stationary stores in my state?

Do I need to buy license for that ? If yes, Do i need to change the URL ?

Comment: Start here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Go into your api console and grab an API key, then go from there:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Answer (score 0):

> I tried sample application by using the below URLs.Both working fine.
>   Which one is best ? seems both belongs to V3 ? Can i use it for free ?
>
> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?**key={API_KEY}**&sensor=false

Go for the first one according to official documentation. But the thing is, what happened to your **API key** anyway!?

As for whether you can use it for free, read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage). (Please show your effort before asking things like these)

Comment: i never used key for the URL

Comment: Below URL is working fine for me without key.                      What is the diff btwn with & without Key ?                  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js

Comment: I'm sure most of your doubts will be cleared if you finished reading the official documentation. 0.0+